# iOS Multiple Bottom-Sheets

Tags: ios, swift, bottom-sheet

I have implemented a bottom sheet using a tutorial that someone else provided here. Everything is going well, however I want to implement a bottom sheet that goes above that bottom sheet and perhaps multiple other bottom sheets that go above the previous bottom sheet. I would like to implement this similar to how iOS 10 maps has their bottom sheets. i.e. if one bottom sheet goes on top of another you can simply dismiss it with pressing the 'x' at the top left.

Here is my current code:

In my map view controller I've added:

```
func addBottomSheetView() {
// 1- Init bottomSheetVC
let bottomSheetVC = BottomSheetViewController()

// 2- Add bottomSheetVC as a child view 
self.addChildViewController(bottomSheetVC)
self.view.addSubview(bottomSheetVC.view)
bottomSheetVC.didMoveToParentViewController(self)

// 3- Adjust bottomSheet frame and initial position.
let height = view.frame.height
let width  = view.frame.width
bottomSheetVC.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.maxY, width,  height)
}
```

And call it in viewDidAppear method:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
  super.viewDidAppear(animated)
  addBottomSheetView()
}
```

In my bottom sheet controller I've added:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()

let gesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer.init(target: self, action:   #selector(BottomSheetViewController.panGesture))
view.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)

}

func panGesture(recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
let translation = recognizer.translationInView(self.view)
let y = self.view.frame.minY
self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, y + translation.y, view.frame.width,        view.frame.height)
  recognizer.setTranslation(CGPointZero, inView: self.view)
}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
super.viewDidAppear(animated)

 UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3) { [weak self] in
     let frame = self?.view.frame
     let yComponent = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height - 200
     self?.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, yComponent, frame!.width,     frame!.height)
 }
 }
```

Originally I was thinking of addSubview in the new bottom sheet, however that didn't work. Should I addSubview to the original map view controller? the button that adds the new bottom sheet is in the existing bottom sheet. Would love you advice. Thanks!

Comment: I would suggest present a new view controller over current as the new bottom sheet.

Comment: @jokeman awesome. thanks for the reply. I'll give this a try and let you know if that works